# Better way to construct an object with lots of data (C++)

Tags: c++

EDIT 1: I'm working on a solution using some useful answers, I'll update the post as soon as I get it working.

I'm making a videogame for my grade's last proyect with a few class mates in C++ (i have been learning this languaje for 6 months or so) and we are cleaning up the code.

The videogame is a *RTS* (real time strategy), and like others, we have a bunch of units that act all the same way, but they have lots of properties. Actually our constructor's code (for the units) looks like (be prepared for tons of trash code):

```
Unit::Unit(SceneNode *layer, int32_t id, Enumeration::UnitType type){
switch (type) {
        // Basic melee soldier
        case Enumeration::UnitType::StandardM:
                moveSpeed = 420;
                attackDamage = 15;
                attackRange = 100;
                attackSpeed = 1;
                viewRadius = 450;
                maxHP = 80;
                currentHP = 80;
                recruitingTime = 5;
                happiness = -10;
                citizens = -10;
                armyLevel = Enumeration::ArmyLevel::Footmen;
                attackEvent = "event:/UnitAttack/Drorania_melee_S";
                moveEvent = "event:/UnitMovement/Drorania_melee_S";
                selectEvent = "event:/UnitSelect/Drorania_melee_S";
                metalCost = Enumeration::UnitCost::MeleeFootmenMetalCost;
                crystalCost = Enumeration::UnitCost::MeleeFootmenCrystalCost;
                path = L"media/unitModels/Drorania/Melee_Soldier_Drorania.obj";
                setModel(layer, path);
                troops = new Troop(layer, path, 4, ID);
                //tex = new Texture("./media/textures/Drorania/Unit/drorania_melee_soldier.jpg");
        break;
        //Advanced melee soldier (mounted)
        case Enumeration::UnitType::AdvancedM:
            if (breed == Enumeration::BreedType::Drorania) {
                moveSpeed = 530;
                attackDamage = 21;
                attackRange = 140;
                attackSpeed = 1;
                viewRadius = 450;
                maxHP = 140;
                currentHP = 140;
                recruitingTime = 10;
                happiness = -10;
                citizens = -10;
                armyLevel = Enumeration::ArmyLevel::Mounted;
                attackEvent = "event:/UnitAttack/Drorania_melee_A";
                moveEvent = "event:/UnitMovement/Drorania_melee_A";
                selectEvent = "event:/UnitSelect/Drorania_melee_A";
                metalCost = Enumeration::UnitCost::MountedMeleeMetalCost;
                crystalCost = Enumeration::UnitCost::MountedMeleeCrystalCost;
                path = L"media/unitModels/Drorania/criatura_drorania.obj";
                //tex = new Texture("./media/textures/Drorania/Unit/drorania_criature.jpg");
                setModel(layer, path);
                //troops = new Troop(layer, path, 4, ID);
            } 
        break;
   /* More code*/
}
}
```

I'm sure there's a lot of better ways to deal with these cases, but I'm not to deep in the languaje features (my bad). The way I'll be glad to clean the code, would be by initialization and not by assignation using enumerations, but I also need to allocate *strings* with the *'.ob'* path in order to load the model, that's why I think that enums is not the best case. What you guys think?

PS: Sorry if I made lots of english mistakes.

PS2: I omitted lots of code, because they don't serve to the question purpose.

PS3: I couldn't find myself others answered question to be usefull for my case, but maybe I missed some goods ones.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding these settings in your constructor you could (and should) have them stored in some data (a file, a database, a `std::map`, ...)

Comment: if you don't want to use some kind of reflection system like google's protobufs you could at least move the data out of the code into simple ini files. If instead, you have a very structured data (like the one in the example) consider using .csv files as it's very easy to write the parser yourself.

Comment: quick (and still not sooo clean) would be to have seperate methods to create different units, ie `createStandardM` and `createAdvancedM` instead of cluttering all the stuff in a single constructor

Comment: There are numerous was to address this.  One of the simpler to implement is to define a struct and a global const array of them to hold all your data.

Comment: Write as an xml file so that you can manually correct any parameter during developmental stage, later you can encrypt the xml file, that way loading/parsing will be easier.

Comment: @mehi Yeah, I see that's what lot of users are suggesting me right now.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I think that's what I really want. The best solution for me should be looking ike: Unit(something B); and build the Unit from that 'B'. I'm not sure if I'm explaning myself correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are patterns that could be used here, such as the Factory Pattern together with a polymorphic hierarchy of `Unit` child classes, but that won't do much for reducing the code you showed (the internals might look very similar in fact).

Rather, I would suggest having all this data in separate data files, not your code. You would then only need one method for loading your data into a `Unit`. If there is some per-unit-type knowledge that is hard to encode in the data files, you can still follow the class hierarchy idea. For example, there could be a `UnitWithTroops` class inheriting from `Unit` that knows how to read data about troops. How far to take this really depends on the (current and future) complexity of your unit system.

Comment: I also tought about inheriting classes, but I think is not a really good idea, because there isn't any different behaviour between one unit an another one (they only differ in stats, and their behaviour depends on these).

Comment: @JulianGR: Yeah, I think inheritance is overkill. I think all you need is [Named Constructors](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Constructor)

Comment: @MooingDuck I'll give it a check. Thanks for giving feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Define a file format, for example INI style:

```
[StandardM]
moveSpeed = 420
attackDamage = 15
attackRange = 100
attackSpeed = 1
viewRadius = 450
maxHP = 80
currentHP = 80
recruitingTime = 5
happiness = -10
citizens = -10
armyLevel = Enumeration::ArmyLevel::Footmen;
attackEvent = event:/UnitAttack/Drorania_melee_S
moveEvent = event:/UnitMovement/Drorania_melee_S
selectEvent = event:/UnitSelect/Drorania_melee_S
metalCost = Enumeration::UnitCost::MeleeFootmenMetalCost
crystalCost = Enumeration::UnitCost::MeleeFootmenCrystalCost
path = media/unitModels/Drorania/Melee_Soldier_Drorania.obj

[Drorania]
moveSpeed = 530
etc...
```

Parse this file and build your unit. You will save a lot of code here.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the way to go, anyways, I don't want to use in-game time reading and parsing a file. Even if I pre-load this data before the game starts, does it really differs from, for example, allocating the data in a _map_ ?

Comment: @JulianGR the main difference is, you are making a boundary between code and data.

Comment: @JulianGR you could remove the variables, just use a map in the class. You'll loose the static checking but you can add new variables easily

Comment: Yeah, you're right, also it makes a bit easier to modify these data (just editing the data file). I'll update the post with a solution I'm already working on that implies a data parser, and an map that stores those data. Hope you can give feedback again.

Answer (score 0):

A useful rule of thumb is to avoid mixing data and logic. That sounds like an anti-OO position, but that's not what I mean at all.

Consider

```
UnitPrototype const *proto = lookup(type, breed);
// code using proto->speed,HP,path etc.
proto->setModel(layer);
```

Now the game logic *using* all those params is completely separate from the all the hardcoded values, and the Unit constructor is much more readable as a consequence.

The `lookup` function I just handwaved into existence could still hardcode loads of magic values (although this is ugly), or it could use declarative style (still hardcoded but not interleaved with procedural code), or build a map from a config file at startup - the point is it no longer matters. There are two completely separate concerns you can worry about independently.

---

NB. Part of the trick here is seeing that a "Unit" is *two* things (and then separating them).

There is the prototype of a unit, which probably never changes, and is how an instance of that unit appears when first created.

Then there's a specific unit instance whose HP and other attributes change over time.

Inheritance probably isn't a good model for this, if your units are differentiated their stats and other properties, rather than by having different logic.

Comment: Hi, as I replied to _amchacon_, inheriting isn't what really fits the pattern I'm searching for. I will update the post with a solution that I'm working on and hope you can check it again.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said inheritance probably isn't a good fit for this.